# Does iMessage work on both Wi-Fi and 3G?

Tags: iphone, network, messages

Will iMessage work on 3G if the sender or receiver isn't connected to a wi-fi network?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question. It's actually already been asked and answered here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29638/if-i-am-not-on-3g-nor-wifi-do-imessage-get-sent-via-sms Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

[According to Apple](http://www.apple.com/ios/features.html#imessage), yes, iMessage works over either WiFi or 3G.

Comment: I can confirm that it does work on both 3G or Wifi. Sender and receiver don't need to be using the same network type.

Comment: It works as long as you have a data connection. Strictly speaking, it doesn't need 3G (it will work on EDGE too).

Comment: This is true, but something to remember is that GSM EDGE data cuts out when you're on a call. GSM 3G data works while you're on a call, though I don't think CDMA 3G does.